# How to run my script file as service in android source code?

Tags: android, android-source

I have created a simple script file "exampleser.sh" in system/core/rootdir/bin/ and added few lines in system/core/rootdir/init.rc file:

on property:sys.boot_complete=1
    start example

service example /system/bin/sh /system/bin/exampleser.sh
     class core
     user root
     oneshot

And did make at the root directory of android source code, make is successfully done, but after flashing the service is not running.
It is not shown in the adb shell, and the file is not added to /system/bin/ path of the device.

Can anyone please help me what to do?
Or the process on how to add the service to the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add below command in your `device.mk` to copy your shell file in your system directory when building:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    your_shell_file_path:system/bin/your_shell_file_name
```

At least, you can find your shell file in your device `system/bin` directory.

Comment: Hi, I added this line, and the file is copying to the directory, but the service is not starting. Any other changes I need to do?

Comment: @PrasannaT Maybe your service has started, and finished its work. Maybe you can write a file in a specific directory of device or print some logs to check whether your service has started. If yes, maybe you should add codes in your shell scripts to make sure your service doesn't exit normally, such as `while` statement. If not, maybe you should check whether your shell scripts has the correct SELinux permission to do your work , and `init.rc` is correct.

Comment: I added while in my script file, it is copied to the device and I'm able to run it in the device, and also added sepolicy and also tried to disable SELinux enforcement, but the script is not running itself just after the boot. I'm not able to understand what else is needed.

Comment: @PrasannaT Maybe you should change `on property:sys.boot_complete=1 start example` to
`on property:sys.boot_completed=1 (I am split line) start example`

Comment: Not working. Do I need to create a seperate init.example.rc file and add the service to it?

Comment: Can your service run always after started?

Comment: I added while loop, so it should. But the service is not starting.

Comment: Maybe you can add a writing file logic in your `init.rc` to ensure your command in `init.rc` is executed. Before that, maybe you should check whether your device `init.rc` contains your modification.

Comment: I tried it, the changes are done in out directory's init.rc, but no file is created and nothing is written

Comment: How about to trigger it manually after system started? I'm sorry, I can't give a more useful advice.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the direction though.